# What is behind the sudden "Accept Cookies" notification on Web sites?

Tags: history, cookies

Cookies have been around for decades, and honestly, I think at least 90% of all people on the internet have no clue how they work. So why, just in the last few years, does almost every Web site I go to now have a "Cookie Notice" that I have to accept? A "Cookie Notice" wasn't necessary for the first 20+ years they have existed, so what's the deal? Is this related to the General Data Protection Regulation (GDPR)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is related to GDPR. As said in [this article](https://www.thesun.co.uk/tech/6507593/what-is-cookie-internet-accept-info-decline-delete-cookies-explained/):

> Why am I seeing more cookies pop-ups lately?
>
> Back in May (2018), a sweeping piece of EU law called the GDPR came into
>   force.
>
> In short, it means companies need to get your explicit consent to
>   collect your data.
>
> If a cookie can identify you via your device (which most cookies do),
>   then companies need your consent.
>
> That's why you're now seeing lots of websites asking for your
>   permission before dumping a cookie on your computer.

Comment: "asking for your permission" - I think most just tell you that they will do so, and you can only click "ok".

Comment: It's a shame no UX person was involved in drafting the legislation...